# Binding a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have an `ObservableCollection` of JobTitles that I want to bind to a ComboBox. Using binding through XAML I've had no luck, so I've ended up doing this;

```
foreach (PresetModel jobTitle in JobTitles)
{
    var _newItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    _newItem.Content = jobTitle.Text;
    _newItem.Tag = jobTitle.ID;
    jobTitleComboBox.Items.Add(_newItem);
}
```

This actually does add all of the JobTitles to the ComboBox (further than I got with bindig) however now the issue is that when the user selects an Employee, who has a JobTitle, I want to select the relevant JobTitle in the ComboBox.

Ideally I'd do this;

`jobTitleComboBox.Text = currentUser.JobTitle;`

However this does not work. I only have access the Employees JobTitle text, not the ID of the title which I don't think helps. How can I display the relevant job title for the Employee?

Comment: what is `currentUser` in this scenario?

Comment: It's an item of the `Employee` model.

Comment: "Using binding through XAML I've had no luck" - please, post your XAML efforts. Code behind is a wrong way in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a collection named: `JobsCollection`. And on this collection you have `JobId`, `JobName` ...etc attributes. Then, on your `XAML` you could simply write:

```
ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding JobsCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="JobName"
```

So,
`DisplayMemberPath` -> Which property you want to show on the Combobox list
`Binding` -> The name of the ObservableCollection you want to bind.

**Edit**: How XAML Element would look like

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding JobsCollection}" 
          SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItemName} 
          DisplayMemberPath="JobName" />
```

Comment: And when the user chooses an Employee with a JobTitle how is the ComboBox item selected?

Comment: @CBreeze by adding another property SelectedItem="{Binding YourPropertyHere}"

Comment: @CBreeze Check out the edit. SelectedItemName -> You choose a name that you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Set your required selected item index:

```
     jobTitleComboBox.SelectedItem = jobTitleComboBox.Items[1];
```